# Postgresql - store 2019-11-03T08:00:00Z in postgres db timestamp, it returns 2019-11-03T09:00:00Z. Daylight came into effect nov 03 2019

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql timestamp issue: timestamp is adding 1 hour to only one date - the date of day light saving

When i store 2019-11-03T08:00:00Z in database column which is timestamp, when i read timestamp back returns me this 2019-11-03T09:00:00Z. I understand that day light saving came into effect on Nov-03-2019 but it should not affect my date . All other dates like 2019-11-04T08:00:00Z works

Written to DB:
endedAt=2019-11-03T08:00:00Z

Read from DB:
endedAt=2019-11-03T09:00:00Z

For all other dates, its perfectly fine.

Comment: *Daylight came into effect* No, it didn't. It went out of effect. Daylight Savings Time ended, and Standard Time went back into effect.

Comment: Please show your write and read command and is the field of type ```timestamp``` (synonym for ```timestamp without time zone```) or ```timestamptz``` (synonym for ```timestamp with time zone```)?

Comment: I am asking for ```timestamptz``` because the ```Z``` at the end of your input is a time zone specification (Zulu-Time, GMT/UTC)

Comment: Please show us something more reproducible than this.  The create table command, the INSERT statement, the SELECT statement. and the connection's `show timezone`;